# How to set xAxis , yAxis in highcharts.chart in html table data column . this data is from oracle db

Tags: javascript, oracle

i have a html having table data like below format .

[image]

the html table code looks like below  :

```
<p>
<table border='1' width='90%' align='center'  summary='Script output'>
<tbody style="display:none">
<tr>
<th scope="col">
SMPL_TIME
</th>
<th scope="col">
SQL_ID
</th>
<th scope="col">
MODULE
</th>
<th scope="col">
EVENT
</th>
<th scope="col">
SMPL_CNT
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
13-APR-17 21:00
</td>
<td>
037z3fuxqsxyr
</td>
<td>
JDBC Thin Client
</td>
<td>
db file sequential read
</td>
<td align="right">
         1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
13-APR-17 21:00
</td>
<td>
1n62665zb9sn6
</td>
<td>
JDBC Thin Client
</td>
<td>
db file sequential read
</td>
<td align="right">
         1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
13-APR-17 21:00
</td>
<td>
1ysky61v6c881
</td>
<td>
JDBC Thin Client
</td>
<td>
db file sequential read
</td>
<td align="right">
         1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

So far i have got code like below  .

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Chart
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="C:\\jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="C:\\highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="C:\\exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="C:\\data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
    data: {
        <!--table: 'datatable' -->
        table: document.getElementById('datatable')
        x:SMPL_TIME
        y:SMPL_CNT
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
categories: SMPL_TIME
},
    title: {
        text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
});
        });
    </script>

<p>
<table id="datatable" border='1' width='90%' align='center'  summary='Script output'>
<tbody style="display:none">
<tr>
<th scope="col">
SMPL_TIME
</th>
<th scope="col">
SQL_ID
</th>
<th scope="col">
MODULE
</th>
<th scope="col">
EVENT
</th>
<th scope="col">
SMPL_CNT
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
13-APR-17 21:00
</td>
<td>
037z3fuxqsxyr
</td>
<td>
JDBC Thin Client
</td>
<td>
db file sequential read
</td>
<td align="right">
         1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
13-APR-17 21:00
</td>
<td>
1n62665zb9sn6
</td>
<td>
JDBC Thin Client
</td>
<td>
db file sequential read
</td>
<td align="right">
         1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
13-APR-17 21:00
</td>
<td>
1ysky61v6c881
</td>
<td>
JDBC Thin Client
</td>
<td>
db file sequential read
</td>
<td align="right">
         1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
13-APR-17 21:00
</td>
<td>
20tmywpvyrdjw
</td>
<td>
JDBC Thin Client
</td>
<td>
db file sequential read
</td>
<td align="right">
         1
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<p>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div> -->
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The oracle query code used to generate this html is given below.

```
    set lines 200 pages 20000  timing off echo off feedback off ;
    set verify off;
    set markup html on
    set termout off
    spool ash.html
    SELECT to_char(SAMPLE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI') as SMPL_TIME
    ,nvl(sql_id, 'NO_SQL') as SQL_ID
    ,nvl(module, 'NO_SQL') as MODULE
    ,nvl(event, 'CPU') as EVENT
    ,count(9) SMPL_CNT
    FROM dba_hist_active_sess_history s1
    WHERE s1.snap_id BETWEEN 40446 and 40450
    AND s1.dbid =  3120820371
    AND s1.instance_number = 1
    GROUP BY to_char(SAMPLE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI')
    ,nvl(sql_id, 'NO_SQL')
    ,nvl(module, 'NO_SQL')
    ,nvl(event, 'CPU')
    ORDER BY to_char(SAMPLE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI') ASC;
    spool off
    set termout on
    set markup html off
```

I want to generate graph like below ( this is generated in excel)

[image]
**Questions:**

1. I don't know how to assign SMPL_TIME column to xAxis and SMPL_CNT to yAxis.
   and EVENT column data as the third variable.
   I googled a lot but didnt get the answer i was looking for.
   Can you please suggest how to do that?
2. I want to generate 2 more plots in the same web page or different webpage .Difference would be in the third variable. once SQL_ID will be used and in the last graph MODULE will be used.

**What i want to achieve?**

Basically when i run such sql in the oracle DB i want the graph generated also when i open the html( i will add the needed programming in the html file using the PROMPT keyword in the sql).

**Few details**

I am a total newbee to javascript/html/java  and dont know much in it. I am an oracle dba

Comment: can anyone please suggest?

Comment: can somone please suggest how to go about.